# Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, primeng

Hi I am trying to use the latest release of prime-ng with angular 2 quick start application . Here is the link for my github repo    https://github.com/svidya/Angular2-PrimeNG

The error I am getting is as follows . Dont know where I am going wrong.

[image]

After the initial changes as suggested down by ibrahim, I was able to get the grid working.

Now I have done many changes after this and I am trying to work with ContextMenuModule from prime-ng , by looking at this I dont think it is compatible yet with full version of angular2 which is what I am working on at the moment.

Please look at the git repo which is updated now again but now I am getting this below error.

[image]

Is it something to do with the routing module not being implemented by COntextMenuModule class ?

Comment: Try changing [this](https://github.com/svidya/Angular2-PrimeNG/blob/12d09a4a1919d33d654afde7bab92de4393d2028/app/car.service.ts#L16) line to `return this.http.get('./app/cars-small.json')`

Comment: wow it worked like a charm !! @ibrahim thank you very much. But dont understand why ./ did not work .. am I missing something ?

Comment: Because Angular 2 will make request relative to your `<base href="/">` value in your index.html.